# How to interface with PKCS #11 compliant HSM device in .Net?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, pkcs#11, hsm

I am supposed to write a client application in C# that communicates with [Thales WebSentry](http://www.thales-esecurity.com/productsservices/WebSentry.shtml) and I need a few hints at how to start.

Device comes with Java SDK but I need to do my programming in .NET. Are there any libraries in .NET that I can use, or will I have to do it all low-level (directly to socket).
Any hints or pointers on how and where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I'd expect CAPI interface for .NET, but maybe there's a generic CAPI-PKCS#11 bridge somewhere.

Comment: Take a look at www.pkcs11interop.net, which provides a .NET wrapper for unmanaged PKCS#11 libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the module is PKCS#11-compliant, there should be a .dll somewhere in the development kit that implements the PKCS#11 API. A Google search seems to indicate that it is called `wspkcs11d.dll`.

You should be able to P/Invoke to the PKCS#11 library. If Thales have not supplies documentation for the library, you can find the documentation [here](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2133) (but note that they most probably only support a subset of the full standard).

Comment: Funny old world, I work for Thales now :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a CAPI provider for PKCS#11, it's called csp11 though it does not support private objects ( you cant login to tokens ).

The easiest way will be to p-invoke into the pkcs11 library from c#, Call C_GetFunctionList to get pointers to the other functions the library exposes. then call C_Initialize, you can use this with the other new PKCS#11 stuff from thales-ncipher too,